# How to "stick" button to the bottom of the telegram bot screen

Tags: c#, .net, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to stick "help" button to the bottom of the telegram bot chat screen. Something like:

[image]

As far as I understand that I need to do that with inline keyboard. However

```
InlineKeyboardButton[] inlineKeyboardButtons = new InlineKeyboardButton[1];
inlineKeyboardButtons[0] = new InlineKeyboardButton("Help");
InlineKeyboardMarkup mrk = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(inlineKeyboardButtons);
await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "<b>Help</b>", replyMarkup: mrk);
```

However I am getting following result
[image]

The button is not stuck to the bottom of the page and if you type the text this button goes up. How to have it always at the bottom of the bot chat?

Comment: actually, you don't do that with inline keyboards but instead with a [Regular keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots#keyboards)

Comment: Inline keyboards are "inline" which mean they are inline with chats, so if you send more messages, it will go up like other chats. you just should use regular keyboards as @Hoi_A mentioned.

Comment: In your code, You should add `ParseMode.Html` to change text to bold.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to persist the keyboard at the bottom of the page, you need to use a normal **Keyboard** and not an inline keyboard. An inline keyboard is embedded inside the chat screen while a normal keyboard is always persisted at the bottom.

This is how you would do it:

```cs
var keyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup {
    Keyboard = new [] {
        new KeyboardButton[] 
            {
                "Help",
                "About",
            }
    }
};
await Bot.SendTextMessage(message.Chat.Id, "My Keyboard", replyMarkup: keyboard);
```